# What does Wit do?

Tags: shattered-planet

There are three character attributes: Strength, Wit, and Health. Strength and Health are fairly standard and it seems pretty clear what they do.

But what is Wit? What does it do? It's significantly cheaper to upgrade than the other two, but that makes me feel like it might be less useful.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 character stats in the game, they are called Strength, Wit and Fate.

- Strength increases your damage
- Wit increases your chance to dodge enemy attack
- Force increases your crit chance

These come into play during “Stat Checks” in random encounters during the game.